Why does my scanner code show as 'not used'?
I have a single screen app with two buttons and a data entry field. I'm attempting to implement barcode scanning for the data field, and am unclear where the scanner code should go, because the Scanner instance shows as "not used".
How can I make the instance visible to my clickToScan function?
package com.example.mngv3
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.common.Barcode
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.GmsBarcodeScanner
import com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.GmsBarcodeScannerOptions
import com.google.mlkit.vision.codescanner.GmsBarcodeScanning

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }
    // Not sure where this code should go???
    // Establish scan symbologies
    val options = GmsBarcodeScannerOptions.Builder()
        .setBarcodeFormats(
            Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_39,
            Barcode.FORMAT_CODE_128,
            Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
            Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX
        )
        .build()
    // Next "scanner" shows as unused???
    // Establish scanner instance
    val scanner = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this,options)

    fun clickToScan(view: View,scanner: GmsBarcodeScanner) {
        // This function is triggered by onClick in activity_main.xmlScan button
        scanner.startScan()
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcode ->
                // Task completed successfully
                val result = barcode.rawValue
                return@addOnSuccessListener Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                // Task failed with an exception
                return@addOnFailureListener Toast.makeText(
                    this,"Scanning failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
    }

}



Your method clickToScan also takes a parameter scanner and uses that instead of the scanner that is scoped to your class. If you want to use the "unused" one you can specify by writing this.scanner.startScan().
